# WSL2: docker-compose command unable to start container process gets permission denied: unknown

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

Error response from daemon:

> failed to create task for container: failed to create shim task: OCI
> runtime create failed: runc create failed: unable to start container
> process: exec: "/code/docker/entrypoints/entrypoint.sh": permission
> denied: unknown

Docker file

```
FROM python:3.10

ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1
ENV PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE 1

RUN set -e; \
    apt-get update ;\
    apt-get -y install netcat-traditional ;\
    apt-get -y install gettext ;

RUN mkdir /code
COPY . /code/
WORKDIR /code

RUN set -e; \
    /usr/local/bin/python -m pip install --upgrade pip ;\
    python -m pip install -r /code/requirements.txt ;\
    chmod +x /code/docker/entrypoints/entrypoint.sh ;

EXPOSE 8000
ENTRYPOINT ["/code/docker/entrypoints/entrypoint.sh"]
```

Comment: maybe try changing your entrypoint for now to be just the shell, and verify your directory structure is what you want. I think the problem is your `pip install` and `chmod` commands should not include `/code` in the path because you already set `WORKDIR /code` so you're actually running chmod on `code/code/docker/entrypoint.sh` and pip is getting requirements from `/code/code/requirements.txt`

Comment: I tried removing /code and when I run docker-compose up -d --build. This error spits out. "Error response from daemon: failed to create task for container: failed to create shim task: OCI runtime create failed: runc create failed: unable to start container process: exec: "/docker/entrypoints/entrypoint.sh": stat /docker/entrypoints/entrypoint.sh: no such file or directory: unknown"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're following the [Django REST framework tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tujhGdn1EMI) on freecodecamp, I came up with a solution.

But I solved it by adding "sh" to the ENTRYPOINT:

```
ENTRYPOINT ["sh", "/code/docker/entrypoints/entrypoint.sh"]
```

Reference: https://bobcares.com/blog/docker-entrypoint-file-permission-denied/

Answer (score 1):

I solved it running a command:

```bash
chmod +x backend/docker/entrypoints/entrypoint.sh
```

Reference: https://github.com/NVIDIA/nvidia-docker/issues/1710